# Problems trying to run rpy2 from a plotly dash application using wsgi

Tags: python, r, plotly-dash

I have recently had a requirement to make it possible to run an R script from my python Dash Application. I have installed R, then installed rpy2, but i get a wsgi error on startup, and then it fails to recognise the modules i have installed, and does not run from within my application.

when the application starts, it fails with:

```
[Sun Aug 07 15:34:31.530051 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637] R is not initialized by the main thread.
[Sun Aug 07 15:34:31.530054 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637]                 Its taking over SIGINT cannot be reversed here, and as a
[Sun Aug 07 15:34:31.530057 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637]                 consequence the embedded R cannot be interrupted with Ctrl-C.
[Sun Aug 07 15:34:31.530068 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637]                 Consider (re)setting the signal handler of your choice from
[Sun Aug 07 15:34:31.530071 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637]                 the main thread.
```

When I run the function to return data from R:

```
[Sun Aug 07 15:37:27.901999 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 5637] [remote 86.151.244.12:59160] NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure
```

Is there an easier way to implement running R scripts from Dash? What is the best practice for this kind of setup? I'm not sure I have set it up right, but there are no troubleshooting guides available. I am using python 3.8 and R version 4.2.1.

I'm a bit stuck here, any help here is really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, worked fine when running outside of Dash, but kept failing inside.

Best workaround I came up with was to make a 'C:\PathTo\Trigger.R' script that executed my self-contained R code, then use Windows to execute the script.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("Rscript.exe C:\PathTo\Trigger.R",shell=True)
```

Not a full answer since it does not yield the interaction desired.  My code is partitioned enough I can save data from R to a csv and reload it in Python without much processing cost.  Hopefully you can do something similar.

Comment: Thanks Jon, your suggestion is exactly what i ended up doing. I'm glad to know it wasn't just me facing this issue, but it is curious as to why Dash affects the rpy2 library like this, must be a conflict of some kind.